# Android Studio slider

Tags: java, android

as i said i try to put a image slider to my fragment_gallery but cannot resolve this problem

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager2 does not support direct child views
    at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onViewAdded(ViewPager2.java:489)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchViewAdded(ViewGroup.java:4988)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5160)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4935)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4907)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:713)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:844)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here the full layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/foto_cabra"
            android:src="@drawable/cabron" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fotoagua"
            android:src="@drawable/aguadulce" />
    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did you keep some thing inside viewpager2 ? post your layout file

Comment: just posted thanks for your help

Comment: You cannot have views inside view pager , you have to create an adapter and set it to view pager . remove the 2 imageviews inside the viewPager2 .

Comment: ok how i do this?thanks for the patience i'm new

Comment: or if you have a tutorial...thank you

Comment: First I recommend you to learn about recyclerView , viewPager2 is implementation on top of recyclerView .

Comment: see https://blog.mindorks.com/exploring-android-view-pager2-in-android ,  or https://blog.usejournal.com/early-introduction-of-viewpager2-ff38c60d2169